# Android Debugger Going Every Class

Tags: android, debugging, android-debug

Android Debugger is not entering at my points. I'm pressing F8(Step Over) for complete the  debugging, debugger jumps to :View.class,AsyncTask.class.

If I don't exit the class, debugger waits for long time. How can I set debugger for going to my point.
Is it possible? Thanks!

Comment: Could you please post your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

Guys if debugger is not entering at your points and jump to class inside. 
Click the Continue button on the left side. Debugger going to your point.